# Find and Replace in PDF

Tags: pdf, find, find-and-replace

My brother studied the same subject as me in High School.He kept all of his projects stored in a folder in PDF format and deleted the original source files. Now I am studying in the same grade as he did and I would like to use his projects for several purposes, but before he exported them to the PDF format he wrote his name and a logo in the top right corner as shown in this picture

[image]

(The image and name is only on the first page of each document) I would like to remove the name and logo. Is there a software which would allow me to do so or does the adobe acrobat have a function to search and replace the image and text in a batch. The format the text is written is also important as the Headings and the text are written in different styles (Bold/Italic) and font sizes, so I would rather not export them to a different file format as .txt. Also I am unable to use "Multiple search and replace" a software from 4dots to replace the text, maybe it is because the text is rotated 45 degrees.

Comment: Edit the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro if the file is not password protected and tell your brother not to do that. :)

Comment: I have more than a 100 similar files that i would have to edit, I would rather find an automated software

Comment: This question is written much better than your previous attempts :) As @jvb says I don't think this is possible, aside from doing it manually.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the answer stating there is no working batch find-n-replace for text in PDFs is correct. However, if your brother's name is roughly the same size/position/background colour in all the documents, you could create a non-transparent image containing your name that is large enough to cover up his. There are automated ways of adding an image in the same location to a batch PDFs. One of those might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *working* find&replace for PDFs.

Some tools (like Acrobat, or Preview.app on a Mac) might be able to edit *some* text... *unless* it has been converted to graphic elements - this often happens if you don't embed exotic fonts, or use special effects like adding shadows or rotation. Or you could "cover" text with a box in background color, and type new text above.

But all these methods invariably have to fail if the new text has different dimensions than the old one... it's next to impossible for a program to deduce text wrapping or hyphenation (a PDF contains text and word box boundaries, so called *quadrilaterals*, but all relations like "this is a paragraph" are lost - there are not even spaces any more!).

Extracting the text (copy/paste into your editor of choice, or trying to import it), editing and creating a new PDF is advisable.